# DIV background doesn't properly fill with CSS color

Tags: html, css, background

I am trying to do something simple, and it's tripping me up.  I have a bit of HTML that looks like this:

```
    <div id="div_table">
    <div class="div_table_row">
        <div class="div_row_label">
            Your Name :
        </div>
        <div class="div_row_field">
            <asp:TextBox 
                ID="tbCustomerName" 
                Width="95%" 
                MaxLength="80" 
                runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator 
                ID="rqCustomerName" 
                runat="server" 
                ControlToValidate="tbCustomerName"
                ErrorMessage="Required" 
                SetFocusOnError="true" 
                CssClass="ctl_err" 
                Text="Required"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="div_table_row">
            <div class="div_row_label">
                Your Company :
            </div>
            <div class="div_row_field">
                <asp:TextBox
                    ID="tbCompany"
                    Width="95%"
                    MaxLength="80"
                    runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator
                    ID="rqCompany"
                    runat="server"
                    ControlToValidate="tbCompany"
                    ErrorMessage="Required"
                    SetFocusOnError="true"
                    CssClass="ctl_err"
                    Text="Required"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

and it uses a style sheet with the following code for the elements in the HTML:

```
    #div_table{
        overflow:hidden;
        width:60%;
        margin-left:auto;
        margin-right:auto;
        padding-left:5px;
        padding-right:5px;
        clear:both;
    }

    .div_table_row{
        width:100%;
        clear:both;
    }

    .div_row_label{
        width:50%;
        text-align:right;
        background-color:#cccccc;
        float:left;
        height:100%;
    }

    .div_row_field{
        width:50%;
        text-align:left;
        background-color:#000000;
        float:right;
        height:100%;
    }
```

So, the problem is that when I browse to the page, the gray background color of the div `div_row_label` only appears underneath the text rather than filling the entire div, although in the div `div_row_field`, it displays a black background just fine.  This is in both Chrome and Edge.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you need to provide the HTML generated instead

Answer (score 1):

`.div_row_label` is floated, so it has no "official" height. To work around that, add `overflow:auto;`to it's container, like:

```
.div_table_row {
  overflow:auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One potential workaround is to set the background color of .div_table_row instead of .div_row_label. Since the background color of .div_row_field is being set, this should still give you the outcome you're looking for.